# replace the first line of text from a file

Tags: powershell

I would like to copy a file from one location to another, and replace the first line of text with a string. I almost have the script complete, but not quite there.. (see  below)

```
# -- copy the ASCX file to the control templates
$fileName = "LandingUserControl.ascx"
$source = "D:\TfsProjects\LandingPage\" + $fileName
$dest = "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\CONTROLTEMPLATES\LandingPage"
#copy-item $source $dest -Force

# -- Replace first line with assembly name
$destf = $dest + "\" + $fileName
$destfTemp = $destf + ".temp"
Get-Content $destf | select -skip 1 | "<text to add>" + $_) | Set-Content $destfTemp
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not a one-liner but it works (replace test1.txt and test2.txt with your paths):

```
.{
    "<text to add>"
    Get-Content test1.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1
} |
Set-Content test2.txt
```

Comment: The operator "." means "execute the following script block/command in the current context". There is also the operator “&” – “execute in a new context”. In our case it does matter “.” or “&”; “.” normally works slightly faster.

Comment: Oops, I mean: in our case it does NOT matter “.” or “&” (strange, I could not edit my comment)

Comment: Readable, sweet.

Answer (score 12):

In the "more than one way to skin a cat" vein you could accomplish the same thing with Out-File, if that's your preference on Thursdays.  Written for better understanding the flow versus one-line condensation.

```
$x = Get-Content $source_file
$x[0] = "stuff you want to put on first line"
$x | Out-File $dest_file
```

This uses the fact that Get-Content creates an array, with each line being an element of that array.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me ("file already in use"). I fixed it like this:

```
$MyContent = .{
    "<text to add>"
    Get-Content test1.txt | Select-Object -Skip 1
}
Set-Content -Path "test2.txt" -Value $MyContent
```

Comment: Just as an fyi, I believe that if you wrap the Get-Content in parenthesis it will work.  From my understanding, that would get the entire file contents into memory, and then (for lack of a better term) close/release...whatever you want to call it...the file for continued use.  Then you can continue on and write to the file.  I do this all the time.  (Get-Content test1.txt) | Select-Object -Skip 1